# django app with subapps. app_labels for subapps and foreignkey relations between them

Tags: django, namespaces, foreign-key-relationship, django-apps, subapplication

I'm trying create a django app with multiple subapps. My current dir layout for the app is *(filtered out admin.py, test.py and views.py for brevity)*:

```
myapp
    __init__.py
    models.py
    subapp1/
        __init__.py
        models.py
    subapp2
        __init__.py
        models.py
```

Where **myapp/models.py** looks like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

and **myapp/subapp1/models.py** looks like:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Foo')
    some_other_field = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

and **myapp/subapp2/models.py** looks like:

```
class Baz(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey('subapp1.Bar')
```

In my **settings.py** I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'myapp.subapp1',
    'myapp.subapp2'
)
```

However when I attempt to run `./manage.py makemigrations myapp.subapp1` I get the error:

`App 'myapp.subapp1' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?`

But I *am* able to run `./manage.py makemigrations subapp1` and the equivalent for subapp2 successfully.  What I'm worried about is app namespace collisions.

If I add a **myapp/subapp1/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class SubApp1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp.subapp1'
    label = 'myapp.subapp1'
```

and then to **myapp/subapp1/__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'myapp.subapp1.apps.SubApp1Config'
```

Do the equivalent for 'myapp/subapp2' and comment out 'myapp.app2' from `INSTALLED_APPS`

I can then run `./manage.py makemigrations myapp.subapp1` successfully.

However if I then uncomment `myapp.subapp2` from INSTALLED_APPS

and change **myapp/subapp2/models.py** to look like:

```
class Baz(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey('myapp.subapp1.Bar')
```

and then run `./manage.py makemigrations myapp.subapp2` I get:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
myapp.subapp2.Baz.bar: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'myapp.subapp1.Bar', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

How am I supposed to describe the foreign key relation between `myapp.subapp2.Baz.bar` and `myapp.subapp1.Bar`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured this out long ago, but I suppose I shouldn't keep a question unanswered. I didn't end up having to use this - it was merely an exercise in making part of an app optional. Having a foreign key between optional subapps was a bit contrived, I was simply trying to figure out how to reference them.

It turned out I was simply confused between the `app_label` and what you put in `INSTALLED_APPS`

In this case, I'd simply set the app_labels to `myapp_subapp1` and `myapp_subapp2`, however, in INSTALLED_APPS, they'd be installed as `myapp.subapp1` and `myapp.subapp2`.

This will both list the subapps when you type `./manage.py showmigrations` as `myapp_subapp1` and `myapp_subapp2` rather than `subapp1` and `subapp2`, which was worrying as a subapp with a *real* name might clash with something else.  For instance,  I don't like how `django-mutant` doesn't namespace it's contrib stuff, so you end up with app_labels like `web`, `text`, which could *totally* class with something instead of `mutant_web`, etc.

Then when using foreign keys they'd be referenced as `myapp_subapp1.Bar` instead of what I was doing previously as 'myapp.subapp1.Bar'